# How to attach multiple files in an email with Android

Tags: android

I need attach several jpg files on gmail (android). I´m using ACTION_SENDMULTIPLE, but always receiving the error "all apps associated with this action have been disabled blocked or not installed".

I found many posts (several here) saying that this is very easy. You just need set the intent to ACTION_SENDMULTIPLE and put all files in a Uri.

Well, none worked in my case.

All this posts are relative old. I did'nt found posts after 2015.

I´m testing app in a Samsung S5 with android 6.0.1.

Any help ?

My code:

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE); // it's not ACTION_SEND

    //emailIntent.setType("text/rfc822");
    emailIntent.setType("image/*");
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + Globais.wbEmailCorporativo)); // or just "mailto:" for blank
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Inventario Holdings = " + wData);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Inventário.");
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // this will make such that when user returns to your app, your app is displayed, instead of the email app.

    //Attaching Files

    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    File foto;

    Uri u1 = Uri.fromFile(file);
    uris.add(u1);

    for (int a = 0; a < Globais.wbFotosTotal; a++) {
        foto = new File(Globais.wbFotos[a]);
        foto.setReadable(true, false);
        Uri u2 = Uri.fromFile(foto);
        uris.add(u2);
    }

    emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

    try {
        startActivity(emailIntent);
        //startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email_intent, "Oi"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro:" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Install some email apps.

Comment: Please try without setData().

Comment: `setType("*/*");`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but, there are three email apps on the phone.

Comment: I've tried it before without setdata. Same error ...

Comment: `//emailIntent.setType("text/rfc822");`. Try `emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");` Remove addFlag().

Comment: Thank you all. I decided to close the post. I gave up on this implementation and will do otherwise without using email. Thank you again.

Comment: I don´t know how to close this question without answer. How can I do that ?